# SVG as heading and description of the text content

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg

I'm new here and have a little (thinking) problem with a project I'm currently planning:

[My Projekt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUhSx.jpg)

In the picture on the left a), you can see the page at 100% screen width.
On the far left, the orange box is an SVG (as a heading and description of the content) that is displayed here upright.
If you now make the screen width narrower (Fig. b)) and/or you enlarge the screen font,
then my SVG should be above the main body, horizontally (above the text) (Fig b) ).
I logically make the transition from state a to b with:

{
State a   TO
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { state b }
}

(The 900p has now been chosen arbitrarily; it should just be a very narrow screen.)

The media query switch from vertical to horizontal now works.
Only my SVG doesn't take part, as if the values in the ROOT are not accepted, the SVG becomes
quite strange and wrongly placed and neither does it take on the dimensions of the values from the ROOT.

How else can I make the SVG jump from the vertical page to the horizontal headline at a certain screen width.
At least the way I have it, it doesn't work.

My current source code is:

```
    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="de">   
<head>       
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">       
<meta name="description" content="Testseite001" />       
<meta name="keywords" content="Testseite001" />       
<meta name="language" content="de" />     
<title>Testseite001</title>       
<style>
        :root {
            --VBb: 50;
            --VBh: 328;
            --width: 42;
            --height: 320;
            --tspanx: 0;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        tspan {
            font-size. 1.25rem;
        }

        tspan:last-child {
            font-size. 0.87rem;
        }

        p {
            moz-hyphens: auto;
            -o-hyphens: auto;
            -webkit-hyphens: auto;
            -ms-hyphens: auto;
            hyphens: auto;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
        }

        text {
            transform: rotate(-90, 82, 82);
        }


        main {
            flex: 1 0 20em;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        h1 {
            flex: 0 0 4em;
            max-height: 3.5em;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
        }

        h1 svg {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 19em;
        }

        main section {
            flex: 1 1 30em;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        section {
            padding: 0.8rem;
        }


        @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            :root {
                --VBb: 328;
                --VBh: 50;
                --width: 320;
                --height: 42;
                --tspanx: 164;
            }

            html {
                width: 100vw;
            }

            body {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }

            tspan:last-child {
                font-size. 0.9rem;
            }

            p {
                moz-hyphens: auto;
                -o-hyphens: auto;
                -webkit-hyphens: auto;
                -ms-hyphens: auto;
                hyphens: auto;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                font-size: 1.1rem;
            }

            main {
                flex: 1 0 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            h1 {
                flex: 0 0 7em;
                max-height: 3.5em;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
            }

            h1 svg {
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 26em;
            }

            text {
                /* Drehung ausschalten: */
                transform: unset;
            }

            main section {
                flex: 1 1 30em;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

            section {
                padding: 0.8rem;
            }
        }
    </style>   
</head>   
    <body>       
        <main>
            <h1>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 var(--VBb) var(--VBh)" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect x=4 y=4 width="var(--width)" height="var(--height)" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"/>
                <text x="125" text-anchor="middle">       
                    <tspan x="var(--tspanx)" y="25">"Rick and Morty": <tspan style="font-size: 1.05rem;">Staffel 7</tspan></tspan>
                    <tspan x="var(--tspanx)" y="38">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</tspan>
                </text>
                </svg>
            </h1>
<section>
  <p>
                            Fooooo
    </p>
</section>
        </main>   
    </body>
</html>
```

## 05-02-2024

I think my actual problem is not being recognized: I am primarily concerned with a desktop PC representation:
The real problem lies here:
State a)  ==  100% screen-width of the desktop:

```
<h1>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 328 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect x=4 y=4 width=320 height=42 stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"/>
            <text x="125" text-anchor="middle">
                    <tspan x="164" y="25">"Rick and Morty": <tspan style="font-size: 1.05rem;"> Staffel 7</tspan></tspan>
                    <tspan x="164" y="38">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</tspan>
            </text>
            </svg>
```

State b)  ==    < 900px  of the desktop screen

```
<h1>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 328" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect x=4 y=4 width=42 height=320 stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"/>
            <text x="125" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(-90,82,82)">               
                <tspan x="0" y="25">"Rick and Morty": <tspan style="font-size: 1.05rem;">Staffel 7</tspan></tspan>
                <tspan x="0" y="38">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</tspan>
            </text>
            </svg>
```

This is THE problem, how do I get the changes to " viewBox / rect width - height and tspan x" ?                                                                                              In what way can I manipulate the svg to "move" from vertical to horizontal.

OR: What possibilities were there to possibly write the whole thing DIFFERENTLY? Because the way I have it now, it doesn't seem to work.                                     That is my current question.

Hopefully someone here can help me
Thanks in advance
MONI

Comment: first, is the same source code posted twice? Thats what it looks like, but I don't want to compare line by line.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about this and this is my first time posting here

Comment: it's ok, no problem.

Comment: Hi, Monique. Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction` for the `main` that is outside of the media query needs to be `column`.

```
main {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @Monique48149 you didn't need to change the media query. In my previous comment, which I deleted in favor for this one, I was just mentioning that I prefer min-width. In that link I still see that `main`, which is now within the min-width media query since you changed it, has `flex-direction: row`. Switch it to `column` or revert your changes and only follow the suggestion in this post.

Comment: it's working: https://www.loom.com/share/9a0de96452774704a1ab1fa2764c8e0b?sid=f7251ef2-214a-463e-9c09-eeafbbbc4df7

Comment: Please look at the following picture again: https://i.ibb.co/1vHGk0f/screen1web.jpg                          The two states that should occur are shown here: on the left side with a 100% screen here fig a) and on the left side of the IMG fig b) when the screen width is narrower at 900 px:

Comment: the only difference I see is that the SVG is on the side for desktop and at the top for mobile. And you said that you want it at the top for both, which is what has been accomplished. I'm not sure what you want, sorry.

Comment: This is perhaps our misunderstanding in our communication. I'm sorry. So I'm sitting at the desktop (PC), now quite apart from what everything looks like on the cell phone, now only regarding the PC: I would like it to be as described in the previous post. This is my SVG that should contain the heading and one or two sentences about what the main text is about, that this SVG is on the side on a wide screen and as soon as the screen width is smaller than 900px this heading is above the main text ( main) stands. That's how I planned it. I apologize again for our misunderstanding.

Comment: Please read my comment from February 5, 2024 in my main post (at the top) again!

Comment: My real problem, how do I get the changes to " viewBox / rect width - height and tspan x" ? In what way can I manipulate the svg to "move" from vertical to horizontal. What possibilities were there to possibly write the whole thing DIFFERENTLY? Because the way I have it now, it doesn't seem to work. That is my current question.

MONI

Comment: @Monique48149 you might be better off using an image, instead of an SVG. I made this for you: https://codepen.io/preston206/pen/eYXKKwV - I'm not able to spend anymore time on this. Sorry. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps, I made the changes by the problem that you were facing `

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  :root {
    --VBb: 328;
    --VBh: 50;
    --width: 320;
    --height: 42;
    --tspanx: 164;
  }
```

`

Comment: Sorry Mansiba, unfortunately, this doesn't help me because it's already in the source code. Please read my comment from February 5, 2024 in my main post (at the top) again!

Comment: My real problem, how do I get the changes to " viewBox / rect width - height and tspan x" ? In what way can I manipulate the svg to "move" from vertical to horizontal. What possibilities were there to possibly write the whole thing DIFFERENTLY? Because the way I have it now, it doesn't seem to work. That is my current question.

MONI

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `viewBox` values via CSS – therefore CSS variables don't work also (and result in invalid SVG attribute values – check your dev tools for errors).

### JS approach

You may add a resize event handler to change the `viewBox` for desktop or mobile e.g. via [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia?retiredLocale=de)

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let breakpoint = 300;

//init
flipSvg(breakpoint)
function flipSvg(minWidth){
  if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${minWidth}px`).matches) {
  // desktop
    text1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(0)");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 328 50");
  } 
  // mobile
  else {
    text1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-90)");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 50 328");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  flipSvg(breakpoint)
});
```

```css
iframe{
  width:100%;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<h3>Emulate viewport via iframe</h3>
<iframe srcdoc='
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 328" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="padding:5px">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none" />
  <text id="text1" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" transform-origin="center" transform="rotate(-90)">
    <tspan id="tspan1" x="50%" dy="0">"Rick and Morty":
      <tspan id="tspan2" style="font-size: 1.05rem;"> Staffel 7</tspan>
    </tspan>
    <tspan id="tspan3" x="50%" dy="1em">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
<script>
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let breakpoint = 300;

//init
flipSvg(breakpoint)
function flipSvg(minWidth){
  if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${minWidth}px`).matches) {
  // desktop
    text1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(0)");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 328 50");
  } 
  // mobile
  else {
    text1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-90)");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 50 328");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  flipSvg(breakpoint)
});
</script>
'
                
 frameborder="0"></iframe>


<h3>Resize window</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 328" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="padding:5px">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none" />
  <text id="text1" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(-90)" transform-origin="center">
    <tspan id="tspan1" x="50%" dy="0">"Rick and Morty":
      <tspan id="tspan2" style="font-size: 1.05rem;"> Staffel 7</tspan>
    </tspan>
    <tspan id="tspan3" x="50%" dy="1em">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

#### CSS approach

You may also achieve a similar layout based on CSS [`writing-mode` and `text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation?retiredLocale=de) properties. Combining these CSS properties can flip your text to be rendered rotated (e.g. from bottom to top).

```css
iframe{
width:100%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
resize:both;
}

.grd {
  display: flex;
}

.col-left {
  align-self: center;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 1em;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

section {
  background: #eee;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .grd {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .heading {
    writing-mode: unset;
    text-align: center;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Emulate viewport via iframe</h3>
<iframe srcdoc='
<style>
.grd {
  display: flex;
}

.col-left {
  align-self: center;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 1em;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

section {
  background: #eee;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .grd {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .heading {
    writing-mode: unset;
    text-align: center;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
</style>
<main class="grd">
  <div class="col col-left">
    <h1 class="heading">Rick and Morty <br>
      <span class="subhead">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <section class="col">
    <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.</p>

    <p>He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>

    <p>His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "Whats happened to me? " he thought. It wasnt a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.</p>

    <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops</p>

    <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops</p>

  </section>
</main>'
                
 frameborder="0"></iframe>




<main class="grd">
  <div class="col col-left">
    <h1 class="heading">Rick and Morty <br>
      <span class="subhead">62. Das erstaunliche Leben des Mr. Kakapopoloch</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <section class="col">
    <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.</p>

    <p>He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>

    <p>His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.</p>

    <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops</p>



  </section>
</main>
```